# ASP.Net - What happend after session timeout expires

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

I'm a newbie in ASP.Net and I have a basic question. I tried to find answer it but I failed.

I use session variable for carry the logged user ID through pages in my web app.

```
 if (Session["LoggedUserKey"] == null)
 {
     Session.Add("LoggedUserKey", UserID);
 }
 else
 {
     Session["LoggedUserKey"] = UserID;
 }
```

I am not sure what will happen after session timeout expires? Will I lose my user ID? And will be the session timeout extended when I'll ask about the session variable like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["LoggedUserKey"] == null)
    {
         Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
         return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will lose the userid value which is in LoggedUserKey once session expires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking whether `LoggedUserkey` is `null` or not .. if it is you are adding `UserId` which you probably must be getting from a TextBox to `LoggedUserkey` .
What is the purpose of else part?  When `LoggedUserkey` already has `UserId` or then why are you adding `UserId` again? You have already lost the `UserId` the moment session expired.

The second code makes sense..
Once your session expires. (after 20 mins by default)
On page Load if `Session["LoggedUserKey"] == null` then you are redirecting user to Login.aspx page.

Also note that the timeout session is reset every time you interact with the server. Such as refreshing a page or any activity that interacts with server.

Answer (score 2):

When the session expires, or session timeout occurs, the `Session_End` event in global.asax is raised (except when session is handled by the DB) and the session collection is finally cleared.

If any objects are NOT holding a reference to any of values in the session collection,  then GC will collect it. However Not much can be said about when exactly will the GC remove those objects.

Also, regarding the session time out extended or Not, The `timeout` says current number of minutes that must elapse before the current session will be abandoned, provided that no more requests are received from the client. This value can be changed programmatically, giving you the chance to make the session collection remain for longer term when required for more important operations.

So, conclusion is that session does gets extended when users performs some activity before the timeout period. If users do some activity after timeout period, session will definitely expire and users will be redirected to login page or appropriate next steps will occur depending on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Your session has expired when session timeout you can extand the session time out in web.config as

```
<sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
```

then session will expire in 60 minutes you can give your custom time in this .you simply can not get the userid when session expire. for example the bannking sites where session timeoutt is only few minutes. after these you have to start a new session if you dont send any request to the server in time less them session timeout

Comment: So when some request is send to server the session lifetime is reset to defined value?

Comment: yes session timeout is calculated from your last request sent to the server.